# How can I do a JOIN using cakephp's paginate method?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have two tables that look like following:

```
RELEASE TABLE
name
asin


MATCHES TABLE
date
asin
```

I want to show a paginated page that shows all the RELEASES that have MATCHES. That is the asin column in RELEASE needs to match the asin column in MATCHES.

How would I do that using the paginate method assuming I have all the models included in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('not' => array('Release.match_id' => null))
);
$data = $this->paginate('Release');
```

Comment: But how will the RELEASE table be joined with the MATCHES table?

Comment: I guess you have some relationships (One2One, One2Many, etc) in models.